# How do I shoot the propellers off of the Guardian Skywatcher?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The Hyrule Compendium mentions that it's possible to immobilize a Guardian Skywatcher by destroying it's propellers -- I've managed to do this myself... accidentally.

Stopping those flying jerks from moving about seems incredibly helpful, so I was hoping there was a consistent way to destroy the propellers - every propeller I've destroyed has been by accident, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing when I succeed.

Where should I be aiming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just aim at the propeller "motor" bit. They don't take much damage from regular arrows, but two or three bomb arrows can destroy a propeller pretty reliably. I haven't experimented with other arrow types yet.

Here's a video: [IGN](http://uk.ign.com/videos/2017/03/22/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-taking-down-a-guardian-skywatcher)

Comment: That video is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've found using an ancient arrow at the propeller motor will destroy it outright. Note that it can still keep flying with one motor left, so you need to take down all 3. I haven't really experimented with other arrow types. Using a bow like the Korok bow which shoots 3 arrows simultaneously will instantly kill a flying guardian if all 3 hit.

Comment: Ancient arrows will always take 1/3 of the health to any kind of Guardian. Explosive arrows can also destroy the propellers of Skywatchers.

Comment: Ancient arrows seem like overkill, since I can just shoot those into the eye. This doesn't answer my principle question of "where do I aim" -- I've taken out propellers with *normal* arrows before. I just don't know where I hit to actually do that. What do you mean by "Motor"? The spinny part? The connecting arch? The bottom, glowy-blue bit?

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom of the "motors" (the big things that are between the propeller and the arm connected directly to the guardians body) theres a glowing blue area. Hit that with any kind if arrow and it'll destroy that propeller. Repeat for all three propellers to shoot the guardian down. Then take it out however you want.